# How to access property of an object inside a list in a DataGrid in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I've been searching for a while, but I'm thinking maybe I am looking in the wrong direction. I have a `DataGrid` where the `ItemsSource` is set to a list of `Book` objects. At the same time, the `Book` object contains a list of `Chapter` objects.

```
public class Book {
    public string Title;
    public List<Chapter> AvailableChapters;
}

public class Chapter {
    public int ChapterNumber;
    public int NumberOfPages;
}
```

I use them this way in a DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Extended"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Available chapters" Binding="{Binding AvailableChapters}" />
            <!-- This is what I tried
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Available chapters">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableChapters}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>-->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My aim is to show the list of chapters inside the book, as a list of strings, where each string is the chapter number (`ChapterNumber` property). For this reason, I was trying to access in some way the `ChapterNumber` property in the `ChapterList` property. Tried to use even the `ListBox` or `AvailableChapters.ChapterNumber`, but it makes no sense).

Example:

[image]

**Edit**

Tried with a converter but, although the value is not null, it says its length is zero.

```
public class ChapterListToStringListConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            List<Chapter> chapters = value as List<Chapter>;
            if (chapters == null)
            {
                chapters = new List<Chapter>();
            }

            Debug.Print(chapters.Count.ToString());    // "0"
            Debug.Print(chapters[0].ChapterNumber);    // Error: index out of range
            string result = string.Join(" ", chapters.Select(chap => chap.Name));
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use a Binding Converter which returns whatever string you like to create from a `List<Chapter>`.

Comment: @Clemens I tried with a converter, but I receive an empty (not null) list. Please, could you take a look at my edited question?

Comment: That clearly indicates that the AvailableChapters Binding works, but also that AvailableChapters is an empty list. You certainly haven't initialized it properly. If you are adding Chapters after the view is initialized, make it an ObservableCollection, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are adding Chapters after the view was initialized, AvailableChapters should be an ObservableCollection:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Chapter> AvailableChapters { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Chapter>();
}
```

In your converter just check if value is an IEnumerable:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var chapters = value as IEnumerable<Chapter>;

    return chapters == null
        ? "-"
        : string.Join(" ", chapters.Select(chap => chap.ChapterNumber));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The source for data-binding needs to be a property, not a field as you currently have.

To get a single string with all of the available chapters, just add a calculated property to your Book class, which combines all of the chapter items from the list.

```
public class Book 
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public List<Chapter> AvailableChapters; {get;}

    public string AvailableChaptersDisplay
    { get {return string.Join( " ", AvailableChapters.Select( c => c.ChapterNumber )); } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property that calculates that for you.

```
public class Book {
    public string Title;
    public List<Chapter> AvailableChapters;
    public string AvailableChaptersString
    {
        get {return list_concatenated_in_desired_format; }
    }

}
```